# Node Red Global Process

Tags: node.js, function

Sorry if this is a newbie type Q but after much searching I cannot find the answer.  I am trying to understand how to write a process (function?) that I can call from any flow in Node Red.  Every time I search "global function" the (web / blog) results want to teach me how to write a simple function in a flow.  I've got that in spades. I'm sure the answer is simple, just finding it doesn't appear to be. Closest I got is writing it in settings.js but no clear examples to give me confidence.

As one simple example, I use a timestamp that is in easy human readable form (12 hr am/pm) for logging. Currently I have to write a time stamp procedure (new Date) in each flow before writing it to the log file.  I'd like a one-liner in each flow that calling a global function I write that every flow can access.  TIA

Comment: I don't know node red myself, but if it's anything like regular node, you don't use globals.  You put your function in a module and you import it into every module that you want to use it in.  Modules are cached so it's not a performance issue.  Just one extra line at the top of any module you want to use it in.  This is required to gain the benefits of modules and avoid the pitfalls of globals.